# Liferay Alloy UI - Clearing cache of dependent AutoCompleteList

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I need to have two dependent AutoCompleteList in my Liferay portlet page. When I select some value from first AutoCompleteList then based on it's selected value I need to change the second AutoCompleteList source data. Based on information available, I have done coding and it is working fine except one issue.

When I select item in first AutoCompleteList then second AutoCompleteList gets populated with certain values based on my first list's selected item. Then if I change my selection again in first list, second AutoCompleteList gets updated with new possible values. But it appends the new possible values in the existing list or can say keep caching of data from both cases. But I need to show only possible values in list based on current selection of first list. For example, for selected value 1 in first list, if initially it was showing [A, B] in second list, after changing selection in first list from 1 to 2, it is showing [[A,B]+[C,D]].

Below here is part of that code. I tried setting "enableCache: 'false' " in second AutoComepleteList but not working.

```
<aui:script>

AUI().use('autocomplete-list','aui-base','aui-io-request','autocomplete-filters','autocomplete-highlighters',
function (A) 
{
A.io.request('<%=getUrl %>',{

dataType: 'json',
method: 'GET',
on: {
success: function() {

new A.AutoCompleteList(
{
allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'false',
activateFirstItem: 'true',
inputNode: '#<portlet:namespace />name',
resultTextLocator: 'name',
render: 'true',
resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
resultFilters:['phraseMatch'],
source:this.get('responseData'),

on: {
select: function(event) {
var result = event.result.raw;
A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>pk').val(result.id)
}
},
})
}}
});
});
</aui:script>

<aui:input id="pk" name="pk" label="Primary Id" 
onChange='<%= renderResponse.getNamespace() + "fetchDisplayValues();"%
/>
```

```
Liferay.provide(
window,
'<portlet:namespace />fetchDisplayValues',
function() {

var A = AUI();
var pk = A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>pk");
var id = pk.get("value");

var url = '<%=getValues %>';
url = url+"&<portlet:namespace/>id="+id;
var datasource = new A.io.request(url,{
dataType: 'json',
method: 'GET',
on: {

success: function(){
var data = this.get('responseData');
new A.AutoCompleteList(
{
allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'false',
enableCache: 'false',
activateFirstItem: 'true',
inputNode: '#<portlet:namespace />displayName',
resultTextLocator: 'name',
render: 'true',
resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
resultFilters:['phraseMatch'],
source:this.get('responseData'),
on: {
select: function(event) {
var result = event.result.raw;
A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>displayId').val(result.id);
}
},
})
}
}
});
})
</aui:script>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.